# Zooming in on a particular part of a BufferedImage

Tags: java, graphics, zooming, bufferedimage

I am trying to get a subImage of a `BufferedImage` and then use this subImage to replace the original `BufferedImage`, to implement a zooming feature based on a user specified selection. However, when I redraw the subImage onto the original image the bottom of the sub-image is not being displayed. I have no idea why. I was wondering if anyone could spot any obvious faults!?!

```
private void zoomImage(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2){
    BufferedImage subImage = originalImage.getSubimage(x1, y1, x2-x1, y2-y1);
    Graphics2D graphics2D = (Graphics2D) originalImage.getGraphics();
    graphics2D.drawImage(subImage, 0, 0, 600, 400, 0,0, x2-x1,y2-y1, null);
    // clean up
    graphics2D.dispose();
}
```

I was also wondering if there is a better way to implement zooming in on a particular rectangular selection and use the zoomed in section to replace the original image.

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that the size of sub image should not exceeds the original image width and height.
For example, if the `originalimage.width=600` and `orignalimage.height=800` then the sub image can be created whose size should be `subimage.horizentalorigin+subimage.width<=600` and `subimage.veticalorigin+subimage.height<=800`.Other wise there will always be dark shadow found at the corners of the image.

- `subimage.horizentalorigin=x1`,
- `subimage.verticalorigin=x2`,
- `subimage.width=y1`,
- `subimage.height=y2` in your case particularly.

The rest of calculation you do varies from algorithm to algorithm.....